# how to use category type in jQuery Semantic UI Search using local content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying show search results by category using jquery semantic UI search module with local contents. but it doesn't seem to be working. It shows no results. below is my code:

```
    var content  = {
  "results": {
    "category1": {
      "name": "Category 1",
      "results": [
        {
          "title": "Result Title",
          "url": "/optional/url/on/click",
          "image": "optional-image.jpg",
          "price": "Optional Price",
          "description": "Optional Description"
        },
        {
          "title": "Result Title",
          "url": "/optional/url/on/click",
          "image": "optional-image.jpg",
          "price": "Optional Price",
          "description": "Optional Description"
        }
      ]
    },
    "category2": {
      "name": "Category 2",
      "results": [
        {
          "title": "Result Title",
          "url": "/optional/url/on/click",
          "image": "optional-image.jpg",
          "price": "Optional Price",
          "description": "Optional Description"
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.search').search({
                        source: content,
                        type:'category',
                        maxResults:4,
                        fields: {
                                  categories      : 'results',    
                                  categoryName    : 'name',       
                                  categoryResults : 'results',    
                                  description     : 'description',
                                  image           : 'image',      
                                  title           : 'title'
                                }
    });
});
```

Can anyone please help.

regards,
Salman

Comment: Looking for an answer to this question as well. Maybe Semantic doesn't support local category searching?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is still not available at the moment: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1917

This is a workaround:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

$('.ui.search').search({
  type: 'category',
  apiSettings: {
    response: (settings) => {
      let query = settings.urlData.query
      let filteredContent = _.cloneDeep(content)

      _.forOwn(filteredContent.results, (value, key) => {
        _.remove(filteredContent.results[key].results, (result) => {
            return !result.title.match(query)
        })
      })

      return filteredContent
    }
  }
})
```